# Points on the surface that are closest to origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, plane-geometry

I try to find the points on the surface

$$E=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:xy^2z^4=\frac14\right\}$$ that are closest to the origin. I started to look for points on the surface at which the gradient is parallel to the position vector, but using the AM-GM inequality is simpler.

What I did:

$$\text{max}\{xy^2z^4\} =\frac{1}{4}x^2 +y^2
+z^2$$
then have squared both sides and stuck. What is next?

Comment: Is this supposed to say$$E=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:xy^2z^4=\frac14\right\}$$

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry i have failed mathml

Comment: Can you use Lagrange multipliers?